# Problems getting the control from GridViewRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, webforms

I have a gridview which is created on a button click. It has some checkboxes so the user can adjust the CRUD access rights for certain pages and then save all rows.

I have another button to save the rows where I loop through, getting the rowID and the access rights to save.

I am having a problem when saving, it can't find the control in the row and when it gets to ID= I get a object referenced exception. If I do the checkbox assignments first, I get the error on the C= part.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow r in gvRights.Rows)
    {
        if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {    
            int ID;
            ID = Convert.ToUInt16(r.Cells[0].ToString());

            bool C, R, U, D;

            CheckBox chkC = r.FindControl("chkC") as CheckBox;
            C = chkC.Checked;
            CheckBox chkR = r.FindControl("chkR") as CheckBox;
            R = chkR.Checked;
            CheckBox chkU = r.FindControl("chkU") as CheckBox;
            U = chkU.Checked;
            CheckBox chkD = r.FindControl("chkD") as CheckBox;
            D = chkD.Checked;
        }


    }
}
```

Gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvRights" runat="server" Width="100%" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvRights_RowDataBound">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Page ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PageName" HeaderText="Page Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PageDesc" HeaderText="Page Desc" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Create"></asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Read"></asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update"></asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete"></asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Paste the markup for your Gridview.

Comment: @ChrisL Added the gridview

Comment: Are your checkboxes added programatically?

Comment: @ChrisL Yes in the rowdatabound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding your checkboxes programmatically you need to add them back in on each page load in the pageinit (before page_load). This way the controls are added on each postback and will get their values filled from the viewstate.

An easier way is to actually add the Checkboxes in your template field in the definition

```
       <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkC" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkC" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: In this case I was able to do this, but it would be interesting to know how to tackle the problem if I had to dynamically create the controls.

Comment: The Page_Init function is where you have to add the controls back in dynamically before the page_load otherwise the viewstate won't load the values back into your dynamically created controls.